# What is the easiest way to get Postgresql set up on OSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

Wondering if anyone could help me? I've recently switched over to Mac and trying to set up my Rails environment. I want to set up Postgresql as my database since I used it with my Windows development. The trouble is, there are a number of different ways to set it up and I just wanted to know which would be the best and error free.

I have homebrew installed too, I see it is available to download through there but has anyone had any experience through this route?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost same answer but using [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation):

```
brew install postgresql
```

Answer (score 6):

[Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) is the easiest way to run PostgreSQL on the Mac

Comment: Postgres.app is definitely the easiest solution. Highly recommended

Answer (score 1):

1. Get mac ports from  http://www.macports.org/
2. sudo port install postgresql84; sudo port install postgresql84-server
3. You may need to tweak pg_hba.conf to allow connections from ::1 (IPv6 localhost).

Alternately, from source:

```
ARCH=x86_64 CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64" 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/pgsql --with-libxml --with-libxslt --with-openssl
make
sudo make install
sudo su postgres -c '/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data/'
sudo su postgres -c '/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data/ -l /var/log/pgsql/postgresql.log start'
sudo chown -R postgres /usr/local/pgsql/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [cinderella](http://www.atmos.org/cinderella/) to get the whole PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Ruby, ... stack in one go. The initial install takes awhile but it puts everything in `~/Developer` so it is easy to keep track of and easy to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the [PostgreSQL OSX installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload), provided by EnterpriseDB.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider http://postgresapp.com/.

It claims to be "the easiest way to run PostgreSQL on the Mac" and so far it has been true for me.